# Mysql select - Get the dates of timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

At the mysql table, there are stored values of timestamps (like 1265138145).
What i want is to display the dates (eg 27/2/2011,10/3/2011,15/3/2011, 16/03/2011 etc) which belong to these timestamps. Is this possible?
(but only display one time the date, eg if there is 1265138145 and 1265138140 then display only one time the date - which is 16/3)

Comment: Take a look at PHP's date() function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a variety of ways of doing this, the [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) command probably being the easiest.

For example: `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(<timestamp field>, '%d/%m/%Y');`

I'm not sure what you mean about "only display one time the date", but using `DISTINCT` on the necessary column should help.

i.e.: `SELECT DISTINCT(FROM_UNIXTIME(<timestamp field>, '%d/%m/%Y'));` may be all you require.

Comment: I will use this method. In fact, what i want to do, is to display the logs of chat messages. So, a user can see when(day+month) has sent a message. (Like msn messenger chat logs). Thank you!

Comment: @Man_E Cool - hope it goes smoothly. :-)

Comment: As i can see,it goes :D Thank you very much! :) (Although i hope that using the query there wouldnt be any problem with cpu/resources, as there already 200000+ records at the table :P)

Comment: @Man_E If performance becomes an issue, I'd recommend storing a date (as opposed to date + time) value in the table as well, as you could then simply do a `DISTINCT` and convert the result (via `DATE_FORMAT`) if so required.

Answer (score 2):

From within MySQL, use [ADDDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) and interval of unixtimestamp seconds to the epoch, e.g.

```
select adddate('1970-01-01', interval 1265138145 second)
```

> then display only one time the date

Use DISTINCT in your query, e.g.

```
select distinct date(adddate('1970-01-01', interval 1265138145 second))
from tbl ..
```

Both queries above return the column as a datetime value, which you can apply default formatting to in PHP.

---

***Note about using FROM_UNIXTIME** - you get your local UTC offset **added** to the time, which is **unlikely** to be what you want, unless the data was populated using UNIX_TIMESTAMP in the first place.*

> [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime): Returns a representation of the unix_timestamp argument as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is used in a string or numeric context. The value is expressed ***in the current time zone***

Comment: What's so wrong with using FROM_UNIXTIME? (Your approach seems a bit obtuse.)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    print date("d/m/Y", $timestamp);
?>
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Doing this in PHP is needless - why not just convert in MySQL?

Comment: He tagged his question with PHP, which is why I assumed he wanted to use PHP. No need to vote our responses down

Comment: I downvoted because there's no need to do this in PHP and your answer doesn't solve the OPs requirement for a distinct date.

Comment: @middaparka Ah... OK, i get it. It wasn't clear from his question that he wanted to _select_ unique dates - he said _display_.

Comment: Have to admit it perhaps wasn't the most clearly worded question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your data and use just [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
echo date('d/m/Y', $row['date']);
```

Comment: Doing this in PHP is needless - why not just convert in MySQL?

Comment: Working with timestamp in PHP is more flexible.

Comment: How is it more flexible? Also, how does your answer address the requirement for a distinct date? Are you going to do that in PHP as well?

Answer (score 0):

use `FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp), FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp,format)`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

in mySQL statement